# How to change YouTube download directory

Tags: android, youtube

I'm MrDual. Recently my mother bought an sdcard. I have put the sdcard on my device temporarily. I didn't knew that if YouTube finds an sdcard it downloads it's video to it. Now after my mother moved the sdcard I can't find the downloads. Is there any ways to move the downloaded videos to local storage without redownloading? Redownlpading would take hours.

I tried to copy the sdcard/android/data/com.google.android.youtube To the storage/android/data/com.google.android.youtube